# compare cipher suites between different OpenSSL Versions

Tags: tls

How to find cipher suite changes within different OpenSSL versions ? Let's assume that  the  OpenSSL package was update to  openssl-0.9.8e-36.0.1.el5_11 and I'm able to find from release notes what was it's version prior to the upgrade. Thanks to "Steffen Ullrich I know how to run a command to list the cipher suites for the current version but is there any repository that would allow my compare both OpenSSL versions in terms of cipher suite changs?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Cipher suites can be enabled or disabled at compile-time, which is why you'd want to be able to run the same command against both versions of OpenSSL: so you can see what was *actually* compiled into the package. Someone could also have backported certain suites into (or out of) the code before compiling and releasing the packages you have. Given that long version string, you seem to have received OpenSSL from some third-party vendor (CentOS?) who is not providing vanilla OpenSSL, so the official OpenSSL changelogs won't tell you what other changes have been made: you will probably need to contact your vendor for their changelogs.

As a starting point, or if you just care about what *could* have been compiled in assuming the code was taken directly from OpenSSL without any changes, OpenSSL provides [their changelogs](https://openssl.org/news/changelog.html) by version so you can see a technical list of what was changed in each version (for example, 0.9.8c removed 3 ciphersuites and added 1).

Comment: That version format is RHEL, which is redistributed by CentOS and maybe others. It may matter here that RedHat until roughly 2 years ago removed ECC functionality from all crypto packages that had it, including ECC-based ciphersuites in OpenSSL, which were in fact present in vanilla/upstream 0.9.8 but in a hard to use form; only 1.0.0 and up provides them by default.

Comment: Thank you both for taking time to comment. When looking at the release notes I can see that OpenSSL got updated from 0.9.8e-**33**.el5_11 to openssl-0.9.8e-37.el5_11 in response to the following security vulnerability CVE-2015-3195. I was reviewing it but couldn't find something that would indicated cipher suite changes ...